# Can't import custom fontawesome web icons in Flutter

Tags: flutter, font-awesome

Creating a custom icon on fontawesome using the icon wizard does not generate the custom icon code after importing the new web files (the `icons.json` and the custom `.tff` file).

I made a new icon using fontawesome's icon wizard.
Downloaded the web files for this kit.
Replaced my old web files with the new ones.

I added this code to my `pubspec.yaml`:

```
    - family: FontAwesomeCustom
      fonts:
        - asset: lib/fonts/custom-icons.ttf
          weight: 100
```

Then I ran this command:

```
./configurator.bat --dynamic
```

However after doing this, it will override the code in my `pubspec.yaml` and place it in commentary.
I have tried placing the asset under another family like `FontAwesomeThin`.
When I name the family `Custom` instead of `FontAwesomeCustom` it doesn't put it in commentary but does not generate the code for my custom icon either.